# quickest way to research a set of pages backlinks

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have a list of 300+ pages (they were chosen based on which pages rank for a keyword I'm interested in) and I want to compile a list all the (known) inbound links to those pages.

What's the fastest way to do this?  It seems like the only tools out there-- Yahoo Site Explorer, SEOMoz, Majestic, require you to either a) manually export each set of links by hand, or b) get data at the domain level (e.g. Majestic's clique hunter).

Does anyone know of any efficient way to do this?  I ask because I'm about to write a bunch of code and I don't want to waste my time if there's another tool that will work.  I know SEOMoz and Majestic have API's but I'm wondering if there's a more user-friendly option.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: I didn't find any products.  Coincidentally, there was a post on Distilled.co.uk's blog about writing your own crawler for link building, which is basically what I decided to do.  I'm putting it up at Wordloop.com if anyone wants to try it.

Answer (score 2):

google webmaster tools -> your site on the web -> links to your site (export and correlate in a spreadsheet)

Comment: The dataset I have is for OTHER websites, for which I don't have access to their Webmaster Tools accounts.

Comment: oh competition watching - no, basically you have to go via the API of some of the providers you mentioned or of the sh*tload of other companies that offer such a service.

Answer (score 1):

Often this sort of thing is better done manually because software cannot really extract meaning from whatever data it finds. You can just start with the most important pages, search them in [Yahoo SE](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com) and export the data to CSV.

Having said that, I have used [Internet Business Promoter](http://www.ibusinesspromoter.com/) in the past, which analyzes the top 10 websites for a search term, showing things like number of backlinks, page titles, keywords and so on.

I don't think it's really worth the money because (a) the on-page SEO is pretty obvious with a small amount of research and (b) I don't think you get much analysis of the backlinks. However, I think there's a free trial so worth having a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome .. Make them use yahoo site explorer and copy the first 1,000 external links coming in (yahoo site explorer only shows the first 1,000)

Secondly, you could purchase SEO SPY and put the URLs in manually.

With Mechanical turk, your work could be done in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Add your site to Bind and Google **webmaster tools** and look for **inbound links** instruments:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home
- https://www.bing.com/webmaster/home/mysites